# Adding a pause button to a pomodoro timer

Tags: javascript

I have made a pomodoro timer using javascript and tried to add a pause button to it.
I've created a separate function that handles the click on the button to clear the interval on the minutes and seconds 'setinterval' functions that is nested in the main start function.

However it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you.

````
    <body onload="template()">



          <div class="container">
            <!-- heading-->

              <h1 class="text-center my-5 heading">Tomato/Pomodoro Timer</h1>

              <div class="container timer">
    <!--              left hand side minutes right hand side seconds-->

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-5">
                          <h4 id="minutes"></h4>
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-2">
                          <h4>:</h4>
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-5">
                          <h4 id="seconds"></h4>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>

              <div>
    <!--             add done message dynamically-->
                  <h3 id="done" class="text-center my-5"></h3>
              </div>



    <!--          start and reset button-->
              <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center my-5">
                  <button class="btn" onclick="start()"><i class="fas fa-play fa-2x"></i></button>
    <!--              //when this buton is clicked reloat the page which resets the timer-->
                  <button class="btn btn_pause" onclick="pause()"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
                  <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt fa-2x"></i></a>
              </div>

          </div>








```JS

    var minutes = 25;
    var seconds = "00";
    var myInterval = 0;
    //initialise two sounds we have before
    var click = new Audio('click.mp3');
    var bell = new Audio('bell.mp3');

    var pause = document.querySelector('.btn_pause');


    function template() {
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;

    }

    function start() {
        click.play();

        //change number in timer

        minutes = 24;
        seconds = 59;

        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;

        //minutes timer function fires every 60 seconds
        //seconds timer function fires every second
        var minutes_interval = setInterval(minutesTimer, 60000);
        var seconds_interval = setInterval(secondsTimer, 1000);

    //has to be declared inside the start function

    function minutesTimer() {
        //will fire every 6000 milliseconds
        //and decrease the mminnunte number 
        minutes = minutes - 1;
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
    }

    function secondsTimer() {
        //will fire every 6000 milliseconds
        //and decrease the mminnunte number 
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        if(seconds <= 0) {
            //whenever timer goes to zero at that point the timer has to stop 
            //so reset interval
            if(minutes <= 0 ) {
                clearInterval(minutes_interval);
                clearInterval(seconds_interval);

                document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = "Session completed!! Take a Break";

                document.getElementById("done").classList.add("show_message");

                 bell.play();
             }
            seconds = 60;
         }
       }


        pause.addEventListner('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
            clearInterval(minutes_interval);
            clearInterval(seconds_interval);
        }

    )};
````

Comment: `pause.addEventListner` has a typo.

Comment: thanks that was the issue it worked